# adding a media query to edit container length make a tab crash on firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I'm new to react and trying to develop my own website with it to learn. So here's my issue: I have a container (a div):

```
.container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

under it, I have two more containers define as this:

```
.left-container {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px #b6b6b6 solid;
}
.right-container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I've added a media query to change the size of the to childer

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 .container{
     width: 60%;
 }
 /*this two class makes my tab crash*/
 .left-container {
    width: 100%;
 }

 .right-container {
    width: 100%;
 }
}
```

in this situation my tab in Firefox give this error meanwhile the Chrome tab load just fine

```
Gah. Your tab just crashed.
```

commenting those two the page start working again and I have no idea how to debug this issue.

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of error, and how did  it debug? Am I missing something about react?